# Searching the path in Windows to find a file

Tags: windows, utilities

I know there is a small utility program to do this, but my memory fails me.  I often want to find the location of an executable that is somewhere on my windows path -- I just don't know where.  I know it is on my path because I can run it regardless of my current directory.  Can someone refresh my recollection? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good answer for this in PowerShell over on StackOverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63805/equivalent-of-nix-which-command-in-powershell

Answer (score 3):

The command you are looking for is a port of the whereis command available under UNIX based operating systems, there is a project available on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/whereis.aspx), a [batch file](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/20/357225.aspx) and a [downloadable utility](http://www.flounder.com/whereis.htm). Take your pick